# Electron deep linking showing help page instead of app

Tags: electron

The deeplinking section of electron docs shows the help page instead of the app. Link I am following is here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app#conclusion

**Steps to reproduce**

- From the link above, click "**Open in Fiddle**".
- Run the app.
- Click the link "**Click here to launch the app**".

**Expected**: to launch the app

**Actual**: it opens the help page (see picture link below)

**Things I've tried**:

- Uninstalled all apps related to electron because I develop several electron apps.
- Removed all files related to all other electron apps from these folders

  - /Users/username/Applications
  - ~/Applications
  - /Applications
- Restarted mac laptop and made sure no other electron apps are running
- Removed node_modules package-lock.json and reinstalled all dependencies
- Looked at past & currect issues in electron.
- Tried this fix and a few other withou success: [Electron app auto launch shows an additional window due to incorrect app path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774286/electron-app-auto-launch-shows-an-additional-window-due-to-incorrect-app-path)
  After trying all these things, I still get the same issue.

Thanks for taking a peek at this issue. Your help is greatly appreciated.

[electron deeplinking issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4LyR.png)